# end a QueryResultList to a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

I tried to send a QueryResultList to my jsp page :

```
Query q = new Query("post").addSort("time", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
for (Entity entity : results) {

System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("content"));
System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("time"));
}

req.setAttribute("postList",results);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/tublr.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

And the jsp

```
<%
QueryResultList<Entity> results =         (QueryResultList<Entity>)request.getAttribute("postList");


for (Entity entity : results) { 


%> <b> IT WORRRKKKK !!! </b> <br> <%

}

%>
```

But i got a NullPointerException in the jsp in line

> for (Entity entity : results)

Comment: Do you see output from your print statements in your controller?

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: no i dont see any output !

Comment: sunrize920 meants if your `System.out.println` statements worked.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I guess a stacktrace of a `NullPointerException` only helps to identify the line and variable that is `null`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, correct. I just wanted to make sure if NPE is actually coming at the for.

Comment: Are these snippets the only code in your JSP?

Comment: By the way, what kind of technology are you using? Are `Query`, `PreparedQuery` and `QueryResultList` classes from some framework or from your own project. Are these bound to the `Connection` (like a `PreparedStatement` and a `ResultSet`) and probably you're closing the `Connection` before the JSP is rendered?